# Gaining access to a variable in another class

Tags: c#, properties

I **HAD** an issue a few minutes ago.

for simplicity sake? I have a "Member" class and a "Race" class.

I'm trying to access the "MemType" variable in the Member class (Which is a private attribute) because I want to compare it to the "RaceType"

```
    private string MemType;
    /// <summary>
    /// Username holds the Members Username (JM6491SHR, MM5642SHR)
    /// </summary>
    private string Username;
    /// <summary>
    /// Number of races that the racer has run (1, 10, 134)
    /// </summary>
    private int NoRacesRun;
    /// <summary>
    /// The % of Races that the racer has won (0.0%, 50.6%, 13.8%)
    /// </summary>
    private float PerRacesWon;
    private string MemPic;
    private string MemClub;
    private bool Gender;
    private int MemExp;

    /// <summary>
    /// Need a get property for MemType to compare it to a Race type (used for validation) 
    /// </summary>
    public string memType { get { return MemType; } }
```

(The reason for the variable is, If Race and Member aren't both "Senior" for example, then a member cannot join the race, since they do not meet the type requirement)

I used a getter (no setter) to get the variable.

is this correct or incorrect practice? provided some of my code for my Member, shows the property I used.

Comment: Though certainly not necessary, you should probably always try to provide code if you can. What you've given us is simply not enough for us to go on.

Comment: Added code to main body.

Comment: Yes barring the coding conventions, it is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Property with just a getter will be fine for your case. Instead you can use a auto implemented property with private setter like this

```
public string MemType { get; private set }
```

Just remember according to microsoft naming convention - private members needs to be _memType and public properties should start with Capital letter like - MemType. Not the other way round in your example.

Comment: It doesn't seem like having a setter would be needed. Would also work to make the property ReadOnly.

Comment: If I am removing the private variable `private string MemType;` in the OP's code I assume setter would be needed. atleast in C# 5.0 :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what your attempting to do is the following:

```
public class Example
{
     private string demo;
     public class Example(string demo)
     {
          this.demo = demo;
     }

     public string Demo
     {
          get { return this.demo; }
          private set { this.demo = value; }
     }
}
```

Now in a completely separate class, you would:

```
public class ExampleCont
{
     private Example example;
     public ExampleCont(Example example)
     {
          this.example = example;
     }
}
```

Now throughout the `ExampleCont` you can access your property via `example.Demo`.  Hopefully this helps you.

Answer (score -1):

This is the correct way. You could have also declared your Variable as static, but thats a bad pratice for that case. For more information you should have a look at encapsulation in object oriented programming.